# scipy.optimize.leastsq fails to fit simple model

Tags: numpy, scipy, least-squares, model-fitting, levenberg-marquardt

I have been trying to use python's `scipy.optimize` library to estimate the parameters of a model but without success so far. I tried to use `scipy.optimize.leastsq` which uses the levenberg-marquardt algorithm. Unfortunately, it always fails to find the minimum of my model function even if I set the initial parameter guess very close to the best fit. Actually, it always returns the initial guessed parameters. So, I assume I am doing something wrong. My model is a simple circle but in order to make things even simpler only the radius is the actual parameter, the center of the circle in the data is known and hard-coded. The data is a 10x10 pixel float image with a circle with center 5,5 and radius 4. Actually, the data have been generated using the model I am trying to fit. So, a perfect fit exists. Here is my code:

```
import math
import numpy
import scipy.optimize

# ========================================================================

g_data_width = 10
g_data_height = 10
g_xo = 5.0
g_yo = 5.0

def evaluate_model01(x,y,r):
    x2 = x*x
    y2 = y*y
    r2 = r*r
    v = 0.0
    if(x2 + y2 <= r2):
        v = 20.0
    return v

def model01(params,data_o):
    data_r = numpy.zeros(g_data_height*g_data_width)
    r = params[0]
    for y in range(g_data_height):
        for x in range(g_data_width):
            xnew = x - g_xo
            ynew = y - g_yo
            data_r[y*g_data_width+x] = math.fabs(data_o[y,x]-evaluate_model01(xnew,ynew,r))
    return data_r

# ========================================================================

g_data_o = numpy.array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                        [ 0,  0,  0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,  0,  0],
                        [ 0,  0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,  0],
                        [ 0,  0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,  0],
                        [ 0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
                        [ 0,  0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,  0],
                        [ 0,  0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,  0],
                        [ 0,  0,  0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,  0,  0],
                        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20,  0,  0,  0,  0]],dtype=numpy.float32)
g_params = numpy.array([8.0])
print(scipy.optimize.leastsq(model01,g_params,args=(g_data_o),full_output=1))

# ========================================================================
```

I hard-coded the data in order to remove any data dependencies and allow the code to run out of the box on any machine with `scipy` installed. What I don't quite understand is what the `model01` function is supposed to return. According to the documentation it is supposed to return an array. An array of what? In my code I assumed that I have to return an array of the residual for each data point. Is that correct? My data is a 2D array because it is an image but my residual is a flattened 2D array of residual. Is that OK? Can someone tell me what exactly I am doing wrong? Can someone modify and fix the code? As I mentioned above, the code should run out of the box on any machine with `scipy` and `numpy` installed. In case what I want to achieve is not possible with `scipy.optimize.leastsq`, can you suggest some other library which fits models using the levenberg-marquardt algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you can't solve your particular problem using `leastsq`. `leastsq` is a wrap around FORTRAN library `minipack`, it calls `MINPACK`’s `lmdif` and `lmder` algorithms. Importantly, it is based on the Jacobian and the Hessian of the least squares objective function. Your target function does not have smooth derivative, due to:

```
if(x2 + y2 <= r2):
    v = 20.0
```

and

```
math.fabs(......)
```

, so `leastsq` will always return the initial start parameter.

You should try to use some method which doesn't require gradient/derivative, such as Powell’s method `fmin_powell`or Nelder-Mead `fmin`.

Regarding what is going on in your `model101()`. It first makes a 1D array of the size of `width*height` of `g_data`, called `data_r`. Then it iterates over `g_data`, calculate `math.fabs(data_o[y,x]-evaluate_model01(xnew,ynew,r))` for each element and put that value in the 1D array `data_r`. Finally, it returns `date_r`.

Your interpretation is correct, `model101()` returns the flatten 1D residue array for your 2D data.